# Proof of $\operatorname{E}(u(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x) f(x) dx$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

I want to prove that, for any monotonous function $u$:

$$\operatorname{E}(u(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x) f(x) dx$$

I use that $Y = u(X)$ and then use the CDF method to change variables in the following way:

$$F_Y (y) = \operatorname{P}(Y \le y) = \operatorname{P}(u(X) \le y) = \operatorname{P}(X \le u^{-1}(y)) = F_X(u^{-1}(y))$$

$$\implies f_X(u^{-1}(y)) = \frac{d}{d \; u^{-1}(y)} \; F_X(u^{-1}(y))$$

And using that $(g^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{g'(x)}$:

$$\implies f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_X(u^{-1}(y)) = f_X(u^{-1}(y)) · \frac{d}{dy} u^{-1}(y) = f_X(u^{-1}(y)) \frac{1}{u'(x)}$$

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(u(X)) & = \operatorname{E}(Y) \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \; f_Y (y) dy \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x) \; f_Y (u(x)) \; d(u(x)) & y = u(x) \implies dy = (u'(x)) \; dx\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x) \; f_X (u^{-1}(u(x))) \; \frac{1}{u'(x)} \; d(u(x)) \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x) \; f_X (x) \; \frac{1}{u'(x)} \; (u'(x)) \; dx \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x) \; f_X (x) \; \frac{1}{u'(x)} \; (u'(x)) \; dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x) \; f_X (x)  \; dx \\
\end{align}$$

I know that the proof using the Jacobian method is much shorter and simpler, but is this proof valid? If not, what is wrong with it?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: What is your motivation of proving it this way? Btw, there is an elementary proof of this that does not use any Jacobians at all, and works without conditions on $u$ or the distribution of $X$ (except that the expectation must exist).

Comment: @drhab Could you post the link to that proof? This was an exam question and I feel like the shorter the proof, the less time I'll spend on this question...

Comment: My first instinct was that this was the *definition* of $\mathbb E[g(X)]$. Whether that's true or not depends on your approach, I suppose -- but you can find a good discussion of this topic here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277800/expected-value-of-a-function-of-a-random-variable

Comment: Search using the keyword "Law of the unconscious statistician"

Comment: Instead of providing a link I made it clear in an answer (too much for a comment).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to your question but shows you another route.

---

First some basics.

Let $\langle\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathsf{P}\rangle$ denote the probability
measure space on which random variable $X$ is defined.

Then $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function in the meaning
that $X^{-1}\left(B\right)\in\mathcal{A}$ for every $B\in\mathcal{B}$
where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of Borelsets on
$\mathbb{R}$.

Here $X^{-1}\left(B\right)=\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)\in B\right\} $
and this set is also denoted by $\left\{ X\in B\right\} $ and $\mathsf{P}\left(\left\{ X\in B\right\} \right)$
is abbreviated by $\mathsf{P}\left(X\in B\right)$.

Further $X$ induces a probability measure $\mathsf{P}_{X}$ on $\mathcal{B}$
which is prescribed by $B\mapsto\mathsf{P}\left(X\in B\right)=\mathsf{P}\left(X^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)$.

This together results in a probability measure space $\langle\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\mathsf{P}_{X}\rangle$.

If $X$ is integrable wrt measure $\mathsf{P}$ then it has a so-called
[expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case) defined like this:

$$\mathsf{E}X=\int X\left(\omega\right)\mathsf{P}\left(d\omega\right)$$
and essential in this context is the equality: $$\int X\left(\omega\right)\mathsf{P}\left(d\omega\right)=\int x\mathsf{P}_{X}\left(dx\right)\tag1$$

The RHS of the equality is mostly written as $\int xdF_{X}\left(x\right)$
where $F_{X}$ is the CDF of $X$ which is completely determining
for $\mathsf{P}_{X}$.

This equality can be proved by first showing that it is valid for
indicator functions.

Note for instance that - if $X=1_{B}$ for some $B\in\mathcal{B}$
- we will find: $F_{X}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x<0\\
1-\mathsf{P}\left(B\right) & \text{if }0\leq x<1\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

leading to $\int X\left(\omega\right)\mathsf{P}\left(d\omega\right)=\int1_{B}\left(\omega\right)\mathsf{P}\left(d\omega\right)=\mathsf{P}\left(B\right)=\int xdF_{X}\left(x\right)=\int x\mathsf{P}_{X}\left(dx\right)$.

Then it can easily be extended to step functions and finally to integrable functions.

---

If this is all well captured then the way is open to prove the equality in your question.

Let $\langle\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathsf{P}\rangle$ denote the probability
measure space on which random variable $X$ is defined.

Let $U:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable defined
on probability space $\langle\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\mathsf{P}_{X}\rangle$
and let it be integrable.

To emphasize that it is random variable I use capital $U$ instead of $u$.

It induces - as stated above - a probability space $\langle\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\left(\mathsf{P}_{X}\right)_{U}\rangle$
and we find easily that: $$\left(\mathsf{P}_{X}\right)_{U}=\mathsf{P}_{U\circ X}$$
by stating that for $B\in\mathcal{B}$ we have: $\left(\mathsf{P}_{X}\right)_{U}\left(B\right)=\mathsf{P}_{X}\left(U^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)=\mathsf{P}\left(X^{-1}\left(U^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)\right)=\mathsf{P}\left(\left(U\circ X\right)^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)=\mathsf{P}_{U\circ X}\left(B\right)$

Based on that we find:

$\int U\left(x\right)F_{X}\left(x\right)=\int U\left(x\right)\mathsf{P}_{X}\left(dx\right)=\int u\mathsf{P}_{U\circ X}\left(du\right)=\int U\circ X\left(\omega\right)\mathsf{P}\left(d\omega\right)=\mathsf{E}\left(U\circ X\right)$

The second equality and third equation are both applications of $(1)$. The second uses that $U$ is a random variable on $\langle\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\mathsf{P}_{X}\rangle$ and the third equality uses that $U\circ X$ is a random variable on $\langle\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathsf{P}\rangle$.

Comment: What? OP sounds to be in elementary probability to me.